# header only hpp files to dll and lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

- Can I make header only libraries such as boost to dll and lib file?

  - looks like yes, right??
- Environment : Window 10, Visual studio 2015, Cmake

  - How can I build my project files to dll and lib

---

- Sorry for very vague questions, but I'm new to c++. So any reference and documentation will be helpful to me.

Comment: A header only library is just included by the client; it cannot be built to a dll/lib.  Some components of Boost are not just headers - these require linking with the Boost lib(s).

Comment: If you still want your library to be built to a dll/lib (for example, if you plan to make it non-header-only in future), you can just add a `.cpp` including some of your headers

Comment: If your library contains only templates the answer is yes.

Comment: With CMake you'd just end up installing the headers like this `install (FILES header1.hpp header2.hpp ... DESTINATION include)`

Comment: ***How can I build my project files to dll and lib*** Search for duplicates for that one. I expect there is a duplicate for how to build a dll using CMake. If you don't find one this should be a separate question from the first.

Comment: Related to the first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225435/how-do-i-create-a-header-only-library

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671383/benefits-of-header-only-libraries